# Does Purview shows lineage for Auto created tables through dataflows by ADF pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, data-lineage, azure-purview

I've debugged my ADF pipeline,
The pipeline contains 4 copy activities and two DataFlows.
After the Debug is done , I switched to Azure Purview to look at the changes done to the Datafactory and I was able to see the Pipeline.
But when I go into the pipeline in Azure Purview all the activities and the Dataflows appear with lineage except one Dataflow.
This Dataflow sinks into an SQL table that doesn't exist , so it auto creates the Table.
Is this the reason why it isn't appearing in the purview??

Comment: What are the sources and sinks in the data flow? Is it using in-line datasets or referencing dataset objects?

Comment: It's not using inline datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, lineage into auto-created tables from a data flow is not a supported scenario. This is on the Azure Purview roadmap, but unfortunately we do not have an ETA right now.